# Is there a private messaging UI (inbox, sent, compose) framework for iOS?

Tags: ios, frameworks, ios-frameworks

I'm building an app that requires private messaging functionality for users to message each other (e.g. inbox, sent, compose, notification).  For example, in the Facebook app or the LinkedIn app, there is functionality to send messages to other users (not email or sms). Is there any Apple or third-party framework that takes care of the views for all of these features?  In other words, I'd like to be able to present an "InboxViewController" or a "NewMessageViewController" using a framework (if it even exists).  Or is this something that is typically developed from scratch?

Thanks.

Comment: Assists with what exactly? The UI or the messaging protocol? Have you researched anything already?

Comment: Researched a ton.  The only thing I can find is MessageUI which allows for email composition from within app. Not finding anything that allows for custom messaging UI.

Comment: So you want to make a client for Apple's Message service?

Comment: I want the users of my app to be able to message each other just like the Facebook or LinkedIn apps.  My backend will handle "private message", I'm just trying to avoid building the entire UI for a messaging system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cocoa Controls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/) has some great stuff you can use. Some of it is cheap, and most of it is free. Some controls you could use the look like the iOS Messages app are:

- [Expandable input toolbar](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/expandable-input-toolbar)
- [UIBubbleTableView](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/uibubbletableview)
- [AcaniChat](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/acanichat) (input and bubbles together)
- [SSMessageViewController](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ssmessagesviewcontroller) (input and bubbles together)

If you are need inbox/sent/drafts folders, you could use something like this:

- [GHSidebarNav](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ghsidebarnav)

I don't know what your needs are specifically, but there are things like the [TITokenField](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/titokenfield) that might help, multiple [pull-to-refresh](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/egotableviewpullrefresh) controls, and so many other things.

Answer (score 0):

There is no private messaging UI available in UIKit but I would check out

#### [iMessage Style Receding Keyboard](https://github.com/orta/iMessage-Style-Receding-Keyboard)